# Boot from USB on Grub showing unknown error

Tags: linux, grub, bootloader, alpine-linux

My laptop has a kernel panic error. So I tried to install a new OS, Alpine Linux 3.18.2, I burned the ISO to my usb and followed all the steps to boot it from grub, after I used the chainloader command and it was successful I used the command
`boot`
It gave the output
`error: unknown error.` Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Not enough information. Show a list of exactly the commands you used in the order they were used. It would also be nice if you can show the output too, if not too much of a pain.